# How to split longitudinal data into training and testing sets

Tags: panel-data, longitudinal-data-analysis

I'm trying to model the likelihood a customer will be delinquent on their loan by next month based on their most current data at the time. Currently, I have longitudinal data and am having some trouble understanding the correct way to split my data into training and testing to get a more accurate representation of model performance. So the 2 approaches I could apply are:

**Random Split**

This could bias results as customer's behavior may be similar in adjacent months and cannot be considered independent. So for eg: If I split such that Customer X at month 6 is in training and Customer X at month 7 is in test, the model will likely be able to predict correctly as it's learnt similar data from month 6.

**Form Groups of Customers and split**

This approach seems to be more independent of customer since all of a customer's data will be either in training or testing, but not both.

Wanted to know if the second option sounds like a better way of modeling this behavior. Would appreciate any other splitting suggestions I may not have thought of.

Comment: A very interesting question that unfortunately was never answered :(